# Remember the declaration of variables in sql

Tags: c#, sql

I'm calling SQL queries from C# code.
How can I keep the declaration of variables that I already declared in SQL?
Here is my code:

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
    connection.Open();
    string s = @"
                declare @ttt int
                set @ttt = 6
                select @ttt";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, connection);
    int retVal = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    s = @"select @ttt";
    cmd.CommandText = s;
    retVal = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    connection.Close();
```

The error, at second ExecuteScalar() is: **Must declare the scalar variable "@ttt".**
(I must split it into more than one query because I make calculations etc. in my C# code.
**The question is the scope of connection and SQL query from c# code.**

Comment: As noted by previous answers, your SQL variables go out of scope between commands.  However, a more lateral approach would be to store the data in a [local temporary table](http://www.programmers-corner.com/article/76) which lasts as long as the **connection**.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are "batch" scoped. Each command execution equates to (at least) one batch so none of the variables declared in the first batch will be visible in the second batch.

The only ways to solve this are to combine the two chunks of SQL together into a single batch or to redeclare and assign the variables in all batches.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are only in scope for the current command.

If you are returning the value of @ttt in your first query then perhaps in your second query you can declare that variable again and then set that variable to the value that was returned from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

From the first command the value that was in @ttt will then be in `retVal`. Why do you need to do another query when you already have the value?

Comment: It was an example. It could mean a lot of uses, by cacculation somthng in c# code and continue in sql query. Thanks.